# KVM/QEMU Linux host Windows client video driver problems

Tags: ubuntu, memory, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, linux-kvm

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with KVM/QEMU. I have a Windows 10 client running smoothly performances wise with virt viewer. All that works fine but the problem is the graphics driver. I have a nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with 4GB of RAM. But in my client (I Use QXL drivers) I am not able to attribute more than 128MB of video ram, there is no Open GL support at all which means that the image is juddered which is really annoying. of course it does not help that I have a monitor with a 5120 x 1440 pixel resolution which is not supported at all.  Is there a way to configure KVM/QEMU to use more graphics power? I have searched for other drivers, other settings but until now to no avail.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

kind regards,

many thanks in advance,

Comment: Lots of info about [PCI Passthrough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) on the Arch Wiki. If you have an extra GPU and hardware that supports it then you can dedicate a whole GPU to a VM.

Comment: Hi Romen, thanks. I have an integrated graphics card and an add on card. is it possible to use that in a passthrough?